# Ninject ASP.NET MVC without default constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I've come across an issue where ninject will not work unless there is a blank default constructor in my controller. I register by bindings in NinjectWebCommon.cs in my app_start like follows:

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IAccountProvider>().To<Providers.Account.Service.AccountProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IContractProvider>().To<Providers.Contract.ContractProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IProductProvider>().To<Providers.Product.ProductProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IChannelProvider>().To<Providers.Channel.ChannelProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.ITaskProvider>().To<Providers.Task.TaskProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IExportProvider>().To<Providers.Export.ExportProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IImportProvider>().To<Providers.Import.ImportProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IQuoteProvider>().To<Providers.Quote.QuoteProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IEmailProvider>().To<Providers.Email.EmailProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IQuoteManagementProvider>().To<Providers.Quote.Management.QuoteManagementProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IImportPricebookProvider>().To<Providers.Import.Pricebook.PricebookProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IDashboardProvider>().To<Providers.Dashboard.DashboardProvider>();
            kernel.Bind<IServices.IAuditProvider>().To<Providers.Audit.AuditProvider>();
            }        
    }
```

In my controller I have my properties declared like:

```
[Inject]
public IAccountProvider AccountProvider { get; set; }
```

but this will only work if I have a blank constructor like so:

```
public AccountController()
{
}
```

otherwise i get the following error:

**Error activating AccountController using implicit self-binding of AccountController
No constructor was available to create an instance of the implementation type.**

Is there a way for me to do this without a default constructor or is this the solution?

Comment: My personal view is that it would be better to inject IAccountProvider as a parameter on the constructor. Does it need to be a property?

Comment: Do you have any other constructors? i.e. `private` ones that are inhibiting the inclusion of a default parameterless constructor? Same on other controllers? (And obv @Crwydryn is correct on the prop setter injection abuse)

Answer (score 2):

Having thought about this, I would suggest that you inject IAccountProvider as a parameter on the constructor rather than inject through a property, I believe this is the preferred pattern for dependency injection. You may have a good reason for it being a property, in which case it might be better to expose the functionality through specific accessor methods. Plus it's a Controller, so I can't think off hand why you'd need it as a property.